# Looking for a novel (or author of it) where the world is a seemlingly endless vertical cliff

Tags: story-identification, novel, authors

This is a long shot, but wondering if anyone can help. Trying to recall a sci-fi author. One of his books was about a world that was all vertical, people lived on this eternal cliff (I think they caught up-draughts and down-draughts to go up and down the cliff).

Another story by the same author was about a criminal who was imprisoned in a giant, inescapable structure in distant space (I think that had a red cover).

Comment: The other book you mention by the same author is Stone.

Comment: Thank you! That was doing my head in. Brilliant.